# Jenkins failed to deploy ear to websphere 6.1 using websphere deployer plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, websphere-6.1

I am trying to deploy my ear file to websphere. but it is throwing below error.. can anyone help me in this...?

```
[echo] Creating WAR... at 11-19-2014 04:21PM
[war] Building war: F:\workspace\PEC_Admin\BuildArchive\providerEConnect.war
build-ear:
[echo] Copy META-INf to prepare EAR...
[echo] Creating EAR... at 11-19-2014 04:21PM
 [ear] Building ear: F:\workspace\PEC_Admin\BuildArchive\providerEConnect.ear
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 minute 38 seconds

Connecting to IBM WebSphere Application Server...
Error deploying to IBM WebSphere Application Server: java.io.IOException: 
Expecting Ant GLOB pattern, but saw 'F:\workspace\PEC_Admin\BuildArchive\providerEConnect.ear'. 
See http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html for syntax
    at hudson.FilePath.glob(FilePath.java:1517)
    at hudson.FilePath.access$700(FilePath.java:168)
    at hudson.FilePath$26.invoke(FilePath.java:1498)
    at hudson.FilePath$26.invoke(FilePath.java:1495)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:865)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:838)
    at hudson.FilePath.list(FilePath.java:1495)
    at hudson.FilePath.list(FilePath.java:1480)
    at hudson.FilePath.list(FilePath.java:1466)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.websphere_deployer.WebSphereDeployerPlugin.gatherArtifactPaths(WebSphereDeployerPlugin.java:234)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.websphere_deployer.WebSphereDeployerPlugin.perform(WebSphereDeployerPlugin.java:167)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:36)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:820)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:792)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:739)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1592)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:237)

Build step 'Deploy To IBM WebSphere Application Server' changed build result to FAILURE

Finished: FAILURE
```

I have mentioned below how I configured Websphere Deployer plugin.

```
Post-build Actions
Deploy To IBM WebSphere Application Server:
WebSphere Connectivity
    WebSphere IP/DNS: 192.168.15.93 
    Connector Type  : SOAP  
    Port        : 8880
WebSphere Authentication (if required)
    Username        Help for feature: Username
    Password    
    Client Keystore File Path       Help for feature: Client Keystore File Path
    Client Keystore Password        Help for feature: Client Keystore Password
    Client Truststore File Path     Help for feature: Client Truststore File Path
    Client Truststore Password      Help for feature: Client Truststore Password

Test Connection
Connection Successful!
WebSphere Deployment
    EAR Path        F:\workspace\PEC_Admin\BuildArchive\providerEConnect.ear
    Target Node     DT-GURAVAIAHNode01
    Target Cell     DT-GURAVAIAHNode01Cell
    Target Server       AppSrv01
    Generated EAR Level     Help for feature: Generated EAR Level
    Start Application   
    Precompile JSPs 
    JSP Reloading
```

My build.xml is mentioned below.

```
`enter code here`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

`enter code here`
   `enter code here`

```
<property name="archive" value="BuildArchive"/>

<fileset id="lib" dir="${dst}/WEB-INF/lib">
    <include name="*.jar"/>
</fileset>

<fileset id="war.file" dir="/">
    <include name="${portal.context}.war"/>
</fileset>

<fileset id="ear.file" dir="/">
    <include name="${portal.context}.war"/>
</fileset>

<fileset id="lib.j2ee" dir="j2ee">
    <include name="*.jar"/>
</fileset>

<target name="providerEConnect.ear" depends="build-war">
    <subant target="build-ear">
      <fileset dir="${admin.workspace.path}" includes="build_PEC.xml"/>
    </subant>
</target>

<target name="build-war" depends="clear,build">
    <mkdir dir="${admin.workspace.path}/BuildArchive"/>
        <war basedir="${dst}" warfile="${portal.context}.war" webxml="${custom}/web/WEB-INF/web.xml">
        <!-- <war basedir="${dst}" warfile="${portal.context}.war" webxml="web/WEB-INF/web.xml"> -->

        <exclude name="**/.svn"/>               
        <exclude name="**/*.db"/>
        <exclude name="**/*.pdf"/>
        <exclude name="css/**/*.css"/>
        <exclude name="jsp/intakeForm/*.*"/>
        <exclude name="WEB-INF/web.xml"/>
        <exclude name="advantis_nch_user_guide/*.*"/>
        <!-- <exclude name="templates/EmailTemplete.vm"/> -->
        <exclude name="WEB-INF/classes/com/igi/phr/util/CustomSettings.properties"/>
        <exclude name="images/client-logo.png"/>

        <fileset dir="${custom}/web">
            <include name="**/*.*" />
            <exclude name="**/.svn"/>
            <exclude name="**/*.db" />              
        </fileset>

    </war>      
    <move todir="${admin.workspace.path}/BuildArchive">
        <fileset dir="/" file="${portal.context}.war"/>
    </move>         
</target>

<target name="clear">
    <delete dir="${admin.workspace.path}/BuildArchive"/>    
    <delete dir="${dst}/${classes}"/>
    <delete dir="${archive}"/>
</target>   

<target name="build">
    <mkdir dir="${dst}/${classes}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${dst}/${classes}" debug="on" includeantruntime="false" debuglevel="lines,vars,source">
        <classpath>
            <fileset refid="lib"/>
            <fileset refid="lib.j2ee"/>
        </classpath>
    </javac>
    <copy todir="${dst}/${classes}">
        <fileset dir="${src}">
            <exclude name="**/.svn"/>
            <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
            <exclude name="**/*.db" />
            <exclude name="com/igi/phr/util/CustomSettings.properties"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>   

<target name="build-ear" depends="build-war">
    <delete dir="BuildArchive"/>
    <mkdir dir="BuildArchive"/>
     <ear basedir="${archive}" appxml="${custom}/META-INF/application.xml" earfile="${portal.context}.ear" > 
        <!--    <ear basedir="${archive}" appxml="META-INF/application.xml" earfile="${portal.context}.ear" > -->

        <exclude name="**/.svn"/>               
        <exclude name="**/*.db"/>
        <exclude name="**/*.pdf"/>
        <exclude name="css/**/*.css"/>
        <exclude name="jsp/intakeForm/*.*"/>
        <exclude name="WEB-INF/web.xml"/> 
        <exclude name="advantis_nch_user_guide/*.*"/>
        <!-- <exclude name="templates/EmailTemplete.vm"/> -->

        <exclude name="WEB-INF/classes/com/igi/phr/util/CustomSettings.properties"/>
        <exclude name="images/client-logo.png"/>

        <fileset dir="${custom}/web">
            <include name="**/*.*" />
            <exclude name="**/.svn"/>
            <exclude name="**/*.db" />              
        </fileset>

    </ear>
    <move todir="${archive}">
        <fileset dir="/" file="${portal.context}.ear"/>
    </move>
</target>

<target name="quickdeploy-IBM" depends="build">
        <delete dir="${ibm.server.temp.dir}\${admin.context}"/>
        <copy todir="${ibm.server.install.dir}\${admin.context}.ear\${portal.context}.war" verbose="true">
            <fileset dir="${dst}">

                <exclude name="**/.svn"/>               
                <exclude name="**/*.db"/>
                <exclude name="**/*.pdf"/>
                <exclude name="css/**/*.css"/>
                <exclude name="jsp/intakeForm/*.*"/>
                <exclude name="WEB-INF/web.xml"/>
                <exclude name="advantis_nch_user_guide/*.*"/>
                <!-- <exclude name="templates/EmailTemplete.vm"/> -->
                <exclude name="WEB-INF/classes/com/igi/phr/util/CustomSettings.properties"/>
                <!-- <exclude name="WEB-INF/classes/com/igi/phr/util/ApplicationSettings.properties"/> -->
                <exclude name="WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml"/>
                <exclude name="images/client-logo.png"/>


            </fileset>

                <fileset dir="${custom}/web">
                    <include name="**/*.*" />
                    <exclude name="**/.svn"/>
                    <exclude name="**/*.db" />              
                </fileset>


        </copy>
</target>
```

Comment: Please have a look at the formatting of your call stack and other samples. It is hardly readable now.

Comment: sorry Allner.. Iwas unable to uplod snapshot. thats why I posted like this..

Comment: `Expecting Ant GLOB pattern, but saw 'F:\workspace\PEC_Admin\BuildArchive\providerEConnect.ear'` looks like you are providing wrong fileset pattern.

Comment: Hi Gas... Thanks for your quick reply... Shall I need do include anything in build.xml...?

Comment: Add to your post at least piece of build.xml which defines ear to deploy and deploy task. (PS. If you want to notify user who is not poster, about your comment, you have to prefix it with `@` like `@username`)

Comment: few part of ear target.
<ear basedir="${archive}" appxml="${custom}/META-INF/application.xml" earfile="${portal.context}.ear">
<exclude name="**/.svn"/>
<exclude name="**/*.db"/>
<exclude name="**/*.pdf"/>
<exclude name="css/**/*.css"/>
<exclude name="jsp/intakeForm/*.*"/>
<exclude name="WEB-INF/web.xml"/>
<exclude name="advantis_nch_user_guide/*.*"/>
<exclude name="WEB-INF/classes/com/igi/phr/util/CustomSettings.properties"/>
<exclude name="images/client-logo.png"/>
<fileset dir="${custom}/web">
<include name="**/*.*" />
<exclude name="**/.svn"/>
<exclude name="**/*.db" />
</fileset>
</ear>

Comment: Please add it to the question (edit the question), not to comments, as it is unreadable in comments. Looks like your EAR Path in Jenkins configuration is incorrect. Check this https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/IBM+WebSphere+Configuration

Comment: @Gas   Hi.. I have configured correctly..  shall I need to exclude / include anything in build.xml?

Comment: So could you please provide your EAR path in Jenkins? If it is `F:\workspace\PEC_Admin\BuildArchive\providerEConnect.ear`, then it is incorrect.

Comment: @Gas yes Gas... I have provided like this..  F:\workspace\PEC_Admin\BuildArchive\providerEConnect.ear       Could you please tell me how to give correctly..?

Comment: I don't have Jenkins install at hand right now, but if I remember correctly when you do a build, you should find your ear in the Build Artifacts.

Comment: @Gas I have changed the path now. this is the place where build is happeng: C:\Users\Guravaiah.Earla\.jenkins\workspace\PEC_Admin\BuildArchive\providerEConnect.ear     it is showing below error:     BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 minute 25 seconds
Connecting to IBM WebSphere Application Server...
Error deploying to IBM WebSphere Application Server: java.io.IOException: Expecting Ant GLOB pattern, but saw 'C:\Users\Guravaiah.Earla\.jenkins\workspace\PEC_Admin\BuildArchive\providerEConnect.ear'. See http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html for syntax

Comment: @Gas Hi... I got solution.. I have mentioned ear path as **/applicationname.ear   it is working well & good...   thanks for your great support....